# How to add to AllowedNames in Naming cop of rubocop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

recently I have a problem with rubocop. It says:

```
service/job/some_module.rb:80:37: C: Naming/UncommunicativeMethodParamName: Method parameter must be at least 3 characters long.
    def job_capabilize(*fields, of: [], autodefine: false)
                                ^^
```

so I updated my **.rubocop.yml** file with

```
Naming/UncommunicativeMethodParamName:
  AllowedNames:
  - of
```

after that my rubocop started to argue on:

```
another_service/another_service_mod.rb:13:24: C: Naming/UncommunicativeMethodParamName: Method parameter must be at least 3 characters long.
        def create(at:)
                   ^^
```

"at" is a name from rubocop gem by default.
So the question is how to add "of" to AllowedNames, to use both names from gem and names I allowed without duplicating them all in my yml?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Siim Liiser I resolved this by:

```
[...snipet...]

inherit_mode:
  merge:
    - AllowedNames

Naming/UncommunicativeMethodParamName:
  AllowedNames:
    - of
    - as

[...snipet...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inherit_mode:
  merge:
    - AllowedNames
```

See [rubocop docs](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#inheritance)